# Deserialiaze html to call action result method that pars json data and deserialize it and display a table for end result

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, json, deserialization

In my view window i have a form that calls the get event method like so

```
  <form action="GetEvent" method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
    </form>
```

this calls my GetEvent in my Homecontroller and process it like so

```
   public ActionResult GetEvent()
    {
        try
        {

            string at = "aa";
            string et = "KI";
            string t = "20";
            string _checkingUrl = String.Format("http://172.22.22.10/SampleAPI/Event/GetEvents?at={0}&et={1}&t={2}&responseFormat=json", at, et, t);
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request=System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_checkingUrl) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
            System.Net.HttpWebResponse response=request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;
            System.IO.StreamReader _readResponse=new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            //The encrypted dynamics response in either xml or json


            string _responseAsString=_readResponse.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer parseResponse = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Event> events = parseResponse.Deserialize<List<Event>>
           (_responseAsString);
```

my Event i made a class in my Model view. its below this method

```
            //return Content(_responseAsString);


            _readResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log error
        }
        return View();
    }


}

     public class Event
{
     // side note this variables are the name of the Json Data that i retrieved
    public string event_key { get; set; }
    public string user_token { get; set; }
    public string event_set_key { get; set; }
    public string event_type { get; set; }
    public string event_date { get; set; }
    public string event_amount { get; set; }
    public string event_location_key { get; set; }
    public string event_location_name { get; set; }
    public string event_location_city { get; set; }
    public string event_location_state { get; set; }
    public string event_location_country { get; set; }
    public string event_acknowledged { get; set; }
}
```

Now the question is. After I parsed the Json response and put it into a object List. how do I display it in a table . so after I click the "Click Me" Button it will go through the method and then a page should appear with the Even object in a table? I kind of figured it out.  I think i could be the event in a viewbag.eventss = event; and then use that in a html as foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Based on my assumption of what you need to achieve, if you have already deserialized the JSON to `List<Event>` then all you need is a View which uses `IEnumerable<Event>` and the last line in your `GetEvent` action would be something like:

```
return View("MyEventListingView", events);
```

This should render your `MyEventListingView`

Comment: how do i go about doing that?

Comment: I want to step through the events in the object and for each object make a new row

Comment: I am assuming you are pretty new to MVC. You can start by knowing more about views here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/views

Comment: oh okay..thanks i forgot about that..thanks i have to go help other people out as well

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to do all the deserialization work and the ASP.NET MVC framework has the `JsonValueProvider` that helps you to automatically serialize the input JSON into an object or a collection through model binding.

For ex. if you have a form that allows someone to edit a employee detail and submit the information as JSON to an action say `Edit`, then all you have to do is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
{
  .. save to db
}
```

The built-in model binding feature with `JsonValueProvider` automatically creates the `Employee` and fill the details from the json data that is available in the request. So you don't need to use the `JavaScriptSerailizer` directly and do all that work.

Second when you want to pass some data from a controller action to view you can do through different ways but I would recommend use strongly-typed views so you can pass the `List<Event>` to the view that displays them as below

```
return View(events);
```

You should avoid using `ViewData/ViewBag` in these cases.